# Investigate the convergence of $\int _0^\infty \frac{\sin x^2}{x} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Investigate the convergence of $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x^2}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x$$
>   Is it converging? Converging absolutely?

I want to use Dirichlet's test for integrals. Let $f(x) = \frac 1 x$ and $g(x) = \sin x^2$. $f(x)$ is decreasing to $0$. Now, I need to show that there's an $M > 0$ such that  $\int_0^\omega \sin x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x \le M$ for every $\omega$.

How do I do that? And what should be done for the *"converging absolutely"* part?

Thanks.

Comment: You can show that $\int_0^\infty \sin (x^2)\,dx$ converges (it's a Fresnel integral, if you want a search term).

Comment: It might be easier if you let $f(x)=1/x^2$ and $g(x)=x\sin x^2$.  Then the upper bound is easy because the integral of $x\sin(x^2)$ is a calc I problem.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, but $\int_0^\infty g(x) \ dx = \infty$, so it's not bounded..

Comment: $\int_0^\omega x\sin(x^2)dx=-\frac{1}{2}\cos(x^2)|_0^\omega=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(\omega^2)$ which is bounded by $1$.

Comment: Oh right! thanks a lot

Comment: @epimorphic: Please don't make unconstructive edits to posts. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexM. `\displaystyle` does not belong in inline math because it breaks visual continuity. And even extremely minor edits are perfectly fine if it comes a few minutes after the last. The question is already at the top of the front page, so does not cause a disruption.

Comment: What is happening for $$\int_0^\infty \left| \frac{\sin x^2}{x} \right| \ dx$$

Comment: We have $S = \int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin x^2|}{x}{\rm d}x = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin x|}{x}{\rm d}x$. Try splitting the integral into parts (since $\sin$ is periodic) to find $S = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{2\pi n}^{2\pi(n+1)} \frac{|\sin x|}{x}{\rm d}x$. Try to bound the integral inside the sum from below to show that it is divergent.

Comment: @Winther, Why is the first equality true? Thanks.

Comment: I did the substitution $x \to x^2$ (should have used another letter than $x$ here), see Alex M.'s answer below.

Comment: Right! How could I miss that? (Maybe it's time to sleep..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides @MichaelBurr 's very smart idea exposed in a comment under the original post, you could also use the change of variable $t = x^2$ which transforms your integral into $\frac 1 2 \int \limits _0 ^\infty \frac {\sin t} t \Bbb d t$, to which you can now immediately apply the Abel-Dirichlet theorem.